# Where or how can I model historical market purchases

Tags: price-earnings-ratio, standard-and-poors-500

I've been doing some research into the S&P PE Ratios and the correlation to the performance of the stock market. I'm looking for a place that I can test some of my theories out. For instance, If I were to purchase and S&P index fund when the PE ratio reached a certain value and sell when it reached a different value, what would the outcome be. I've seen that Investopedia has a [simulator](http://www.investopedia.com/simulator/) but it only allows you to play the game moving forward not historically. Any resources would be great.

Answer (score 2):

[Robert Shiller](http://www.econ.yale.edu/~shiller/data.htm) has an on-line page with links to download some historical data that may be what you want here. [Center for the Research in Security Prices](http://www.crsp.com/products/software-access-tools) would be my suggestion for another resource here.

Comment: My thought exactly, the Shiller data.

Answer (score 1):

This site should help you to accomplish what you are looking for: https://www.quantopian.com